# DateTime Formatting in Silverlight XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a DateTime value returned from my server. The DateTime value is in UTC. I am binding to that data in the XAML in my Silverlight app. How do I convert that UTC date to a local date in my XAML?

Comment: Don't covert it in your XAML, do it before that.  This most likely belongs in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in XAML, you will need to create a converter class that implements the IValueConverter interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Then, in your XAML, apply the converter when doing the binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatter}}"/>
```